# C Drop compiler error if init function wasn't called

Tags: c

I would like to make something like a class in C and to notify the developer if the "class" wasn't initialized before using it's functions. It's easy to do while the code is running but it would be better during compile time.

If I call the get_something() before init() I would like to drop an error during compile. Is it possible?

```
//something.c
void init() {...}

int get_something() {...}

//main.c
int main()
{
#include something.h

get_something(); //pls drop compile error because wasn't initialized
return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the compiler could determine whether a program **never** used a class without initializing it, then somebody could write a program Z that first used the same software as the compiler to determine whether Z never used a class without initializing it and second used the class without initializing it if and only if the determination indicated Z never used the class without initializing it. This would be a contradiction, and therefore such software cannot exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the general case it's not doable at compile time, since there is no way to convey such requirements, and even if there were, it might not be possible for the compiler to prove in every case that all code paths leading to `get_something` have first called `init`.

In some special cases you might be able to get a compile-time warning through some questionable hacks, e.g., have your `something.h` contain `static void init(void) { real_init(); }` – then some compilers with enough warnings enabled will warn of an unused `static` function `init` unless you call it (from anywhere – there might still be code paths that don't call it).

At runtime, you could keep track of whether `init` has been called and `assert` that it has been called in everything that depends on it. (The `assert` macro can then be compiled to nothingness in production code, see documentation.)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no way to do that, a very very ugly trick if you can use static asserts (C11) and the `__COUNTER__` predefined macro is check if `init()` is called at some point in the program, something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define init() do {__COUNTER__; init();} while(0);

void (init)(void) // parenthesis prevents the expansion and allows you 
                  // to call a macro with the same name
{
    /* ... */
}

int get_something(void)
{
    /* ... */
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    static_assert(__COUNTER__ == 1, "init() is never used");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure how this would work in practice if `init` and `get_something` are in a different compilation unit than `main`. Also, putting the `static_assert` in their code would be the responsibility of the user of the `something` library, so they might as well be instructed to put `init()` instead… =)

Comment: As I see it's a bad idea in practice.
Maybe it's better if I make sure if the `init()` will run.
Do you think that's a good methodology if I use `__attribute__((constructor))` for `init()`?

Comment: @Arkku, RandomCounter, of course it is a very bad idea, I will not check those kind of things at compile time (neither with the `constructor` attribute)

Comment: @RandomCounter The `constructor` attribute is a non-standard compiler extension, and AFAIK it also makes the constructor be called automatically when the library is loaded (don't trust me on this, though, I have never used it). Forcing the `init` to be called may indeed be a valid strategy, but then it's a different question… (A standard approach could be to return the rest of the functions as pointers inside a `struct` that you can only populate with `init`, but of course the function pointers change the syntax and may carry a performance penalty, etc.)

Comment: Then I will make a standard runtime error check like:
`get_something() {if (init_private_variable == 0) return -1; else ...}`
Thank you for the help

Comment: @RandomCounter If you are putting that check in there for good, perhaps you could actually call `init` if it hasn't been called. If you don't want that to be guaranteed (i.e., you want to catch the errors and force them to be fixed), then I would suggest `assert(init_private_variable != 0)` instead.

Comment: @Arkku yes, that's a good advice, force the call to `init()` if some flag is not set can do the trick